# Java Spring Paramater of Method Required a Bean that could not be Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing an Java Spring application that sends Emails. I am retrieving data (Email addresses) from a SQL Database. I imported the database repository I need but Spring fails to inject that depenedny. My Mail serice looks like this:

```
@Service
public class MailService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailService.class);
    private final static String USER = "user";
    private final String baseUrl;
    private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;
    private final JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender;
    private final MessageSource messageSource;
    private final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public MailService(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties, JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender,
                       MessageSource messageSource, SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {

        this.applicationProperties = applicationProperties;
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
        this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
        baseUrl = applicationProperties.getBaseUrl();

        javaMailSender.setPort(applicationProperties.getPort());
        javaMailSender.setHost(applicationProperties.getHostName());
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method setUserRepository in com.test.mail.service.MailService required a bean of type 'com.test.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

Does anyone know what this might be? Thanks.

Comment: Just making sure, have you annotated the UserRepository Implementation with ```@Component``` or ```@Repository``` ?

Comment: Yes the Repository is annotated. It's also in a separate project so I had to import it into the MailService class.

Comment: In that case, it could be that Spring isn't detecting your other project. Have you tried adding ```@ComponentScan(basePackages = "OTHER_PACKAGE")``` in your Spring Application class.

Comment: @Vishal This solved it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As it was mantained in comments: `@ComponentScan` should be added.
For example:

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.repository")
@Configuration
public class SpringComponentScanApp {
```